# Has "The Patricide" by Georgian author Alexander Kazbegi been published in translation in any other language than Georgian?

Tags: georgian-language, alexander-kazbegi, the-patricide

Searches in the catalogues of the British Library, the Bibliothèque Nationale in France, and the Library of Congress in the United States, as well as at Worldcat.com, didn't unearth anything to suggest that [this novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Patricide) by [Alexander Kazbegi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Kazbegi) has ever been published in translation...but perhaps a published translation is hiding away somewhere?

In the original Georgian, the book is published online [here](http://www.nplg.gov.ge/ebooks/authors/aleksandre_kazbegi/mamis%20mkvleli.pdf) by the Georgian National Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Russian translation, [for example here](https://www.litres.ru/aleksandr-kazbegi/otceubiyca/chitat-onlayn/)

Comment: Many thanks. Have downloaded that translation now. Apparently there was also a [1923 silent film](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0230911/), although I have not been able to download a copy.